# Как отсортировать один массив по расположению элементов в другом массиве в Python?

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет, такая ситуация Есть массив объектов для условности aaa. Есть массив идентификаторов возможных объектов bbb.В массиве aaa могут быть объекты,идентификаторов которых нету в bbb, и наоборот, в bbb могут быть ids, объектов с которыми нету в aaa. Каким образом я могу взять объекты из aaa, которые есть в bbb, еще и расположить в том же порядке, как они быи бы в bbb + применить доп фильтры по которым брать или не брать объект из aaa

Comment: А давайте-ка пользоваться общепринятой, а не придуманной вами терминологией.  Так вот, в массивах ( в любом языке программировании, а не только в Python, кстати) нет понятия "идентификатор объекта". Есть понятие "значения элемента". Есть понятие "индекс элемента". А идентификатор есть у всего массива целиком.  Ну а дальше -  вообще какой-то набор слов "массив идентификаторов возможных объектов" и пр. Если все это для вас в новость -  то рекомендую ознакомится с данной темой либо по учебнику, либо даже по любому источнику в интернет. И переписать вопрос так, что-бы его можно было понять.

Comment: Примеры давай! И хорошо бы ещё свои попытки решения )

Comment: Есть массив a=[{"id":0; "name": "abc"}, ..........] . Есть массив b=[1,18,33.5]. В массиве b хранятcя нокоторые id из a. Cуть в том, что есть id  в массиве а, которых нету в b и наоборот, в b есть значения, которы[ нету в поле id в a. нужно из a извлеxь те объекты, у которых id есть в массиве b, при этом эти объекты расположить в таком же порядке, как находятся значения идентификаторов в массиве b

Comment: то есть пример  a=[{"id":1; "name": "abc"}, {"id":2; "name": "ggg"}. {"id":3; "name": "yyy"}, {"id":4; "name": "xxx"]; второй массив b [33,4,55,11,8,1]; результат: [{"id":4; "name": "xxx"}, {"id":1; "name": "abc"}]

Comment: Всё это надо добавить в вопрос. В комментариях плохо с форматированием

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая функция, как sorted():

```
a = ['aaa', 'asd', 'aab']
a = sorted(a)

print(a)
```

вывод:

```
['aaa', 'aab', 'asd']
```

Comment: То, что вы выучили функцию сортировки, это похвально. Но какое отношение это имеет к вопросу???  Начнем с простого -  где у вас два массива, о которых спрашивает ТС?